# Mysql query for pairs of interconnected stations

Tags: mysql, join

Greetings to Everyone!

I have been pondering on this for a couple of days, was hoping someone can point me in the right direction:

I have a table with station links:

```
stationID
lineID
```

I want to generate station pairs between all connected stations. Stations will be connected in two cases.

1. if they have same lineID (i.e. they are directly connected)
2. if lines intersect (lines intersect if they have any common stations).

How would I do this? Thanks in advance for your input and ideas!

Comment: I don't understand the second requirement: how can lines "intersect" if each station can only be associated with one line?

Comment: I never said that each station can be associated with one line. Stations can be repeated as many times as necessary with different lineIDs.

Comment: I'll edit the question a little bit, I can see how it could sound confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the `lineID` in the `station` table. Instead, use three tables: `station`, `line`, and `station_line`. The third table combines stations with lines, giving the possibility of a station having zero, one, or more lines.

```
station:
  ID
  name

line:
  ID
  name

station_line:
  station
  line
```

Comment: Tom, thanks. I have actually simplified things a lot in my question not to make it sound too confusing. Stations are stored in separate table along with all station details. Lines are also stored in different table with information about the service. The table I'm talking about has stationID, lineID, stationIdex (consequtive number of the station on this particular line).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de187f/3)):

```
select distinct a.stationName as 'st1', b.stationName as 'st2', a.lineId from 
tbl as a, tbl as b where 
(a.lineId in (select lineId from tbl where stationId in 
              (select stationId from tbl where lineId=b.lineId)) && 
 a.stationId<>b.stationId) ;
```

Comment: Meherzad, thanks, appreciate this! This query helps to link stations, which are on the same line (case 1). That was the easier part of the question. I don' think it links stations that are on different althout intersecting lines (case 2). THis is the one I seem to have most trouble with.

Comment: Check the fiddle i have updated the query. But this is not one of the ideal solution. It would be better if you normalize your table so that it becomes easy at time of querying.

Comment: Hmm...now, this is interesting! I want to play around with this solution a bit more but looks promising and going in the right direction! Will also have to see how heavy it can get on a larger table. Thanks a lot, appreciate your help!